# How do I pronounce "Sauron"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, languages, sauron, pronunciation

I have always pronounced Sauron like 'S-ow-ron', after reading Appendix E of *the Lord of the Rings*, but now I just listened to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ypIGdt2uvY) recording of Tolkien reciting the Eagles' Song, and it sounds like he is saying "Saw-ron".

Did I mis-hear it, or did Tolkien do a mistake? Or am I supposed to pronounce it that way, and he wrote "Sauron" so that people would read it as "Sawron"? Highly unlikely, I think . . .

Comment: I'm at the office, I can see that video, but did Tolkien pronounces the name just one time or more? If it's more than one, I don't think he mistakes it, and that's how it should be pronounce. If the creator of something say how to pronounce his creation, that pronunciation becomes the most correct one.

Comment: Yes indeed. If you include a pronunciation guide that explicitly tells people how to pronounce a word, then mis-pronounce it, your fans have a right to assume it's just your accent at fault.

Comment: Note that in the new Hobbit movies they are very careful to pronounce "smaug" as "smawg" and not "smog".

Comment: This is not a duplicate of *Is "Smaug" pronounced "Smog"*, since the Hobbit quite probably has less strict pronunciation than the Lord of the Rings.

Comment: @MadTux Plus the answer over there is based on LOTR Wikia and Yahoo Answers (shock, horror). I've reopened this question with a proper canon source.

Comment: Sauron, Sauroff.

Comment: The problem here is that the instruction "pronounce as English XYZ" is not the same as "pronounce as American XYZ." Tolkien was a linguist and was attuned to these nuances. Listen to him speak: Sah-oo-ron, which incorporates a diphthong as Christopher explains. This is neither Saw-ron nor Sow-ron. Americans pronounce "loud," "how," "saw," and "sour" differently. An American accent would render it Sour-on---but do not use an American accent.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The correct pronunciation of Sauron is /ˈsaʊrɒn/, as in "sour". This is specified in the pronunciation notes included in *The Silmarillion*, in the *Note on Pronunciation* section:

> "the first syllable of Sauron is like English sour, not sore"

and in *[The Children of Hurin](http://books.google.fr/books?id=SSDxnx-ozrUC&lpg=PT27&ots=6eTBRQBSGl&dq=sauron%20pronunciation%20children%20hurin&hl=fr&pg=PT27#v=onepage&q=sauron%20pronunciation%20children%20hurin&f=false)*:

> "AU" has the value of English *ow* in *town*; thus the first vowel of *Sauron* is like English *sour* not *sore*.

Tolkien pronunciation indeed seems correct to me, as a non-native english speaker (not surprising, considering he was a linguist ;))

Comment: Thanks for the quote specifically about Sauron, that confirmed my belief that Tolkien either did a mistake in the video, or the pronunciation wasn't so fixed back when he did the video.

Comment: @MadTux It does appear likely that the writing was still being worked on when this recording was made. Notice he says *Tower* instead of *Minas*.

Comment: I think there's some across-the-pond effect going on here: I would never in a million years think of pronouncing "Sauron" like "sore". My confusion is rather about "saw" (the woodcutting implement) vs. "sow" (as in female pig, not the verb meaning to plant). To me, the -au- spelling implies it ought to pronounced like "saw" (e.g. *author*, *pause*), so the "Smowg" pronunciation just sounds Totally Wrong to me.

Comment: @Martha In British English "sore" and "saw" have identical pronunciations.

Comment: 'To me, the -au- spelling implies it ought to pronounced like "saw"' - but Tolkien wanted Quenya to be reminiscent of Latin, and the Latin pronunciation scheme he would have been taught gives 'au' the MOUTH vowel.

Comment: I imagine, for Americans at least, pronouncing it "sore" probably comes from the common pronunciation of "dinosaur" ("DINE-uh-sore"). To be fair, I've also heard "DINE-uh-sour" and "DINE-uh-sahr".

Comment: Goddammit! +1 for teaching me I've been saying it wrong all these years :-(

Comment: Yes, it's "sour" but it's English sour, not American sour. Same with Smaug. It's not Smowg. It's Smah-oog.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at Tolkien's Appendix E in *The Lord of the Rings*, we see the following about "au".

> In Quenya ui, oi, ai and iu, eu, **au** are diphthongs (that is, **pronounced in one syllable**). ... All these diphthongs were ‘falling’ diphthongs, that is stressed on the first element, and composed of the simple vowels run together. Thus ... **au (aw) as in loud, how and not as in laud, haw.**
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Appendix E - "Writing and Spelling"</sub>

Others, including Christopher Tolkien, have provided more detailed pronunciation guides.

> **AU** has the value of English ow in town; thus the first syllable of Aulë is like English owl, and **the first syllable of Sauron is like English sour, not sore.**
> <sub>*The Silmarillion* - "Note on Pronunciation"</sub>

I have found six distinct recordings of Tolkien saying "Sauron" spread out over a sixteen year period, and it seems to me that the way Tolkien pronounces it is more or less consistent and in line with the description he gave.

> [6:58 - 7:04] He was come to the heart of the realm of **Sauron** and the forges of his ancient might
> <sub>August 1952 Recording</sub>

> [0:14-0:16] for the realm of **Sauron** is ended forever
> <sub>August 1952 Recording</sub>

> [0:07-0:10] And I do not see a **Sauron**
> <sub>March 1958 Recording</sub>

> [5:48 - 5:54] Morgoth, the Prime Mover of evil, of whom **Sauron** was only a petty lieutenant
> <sub>January 1965 Recording</sub>

> [11:25-11:32] whose work had led to the downfall of **Sauron**, also, she passed the great temptation when the Ring was actually offered to her by **Sauron**
> <sub>February 1968 Recording</sub>